# Spring MVC: How to reroute to a different controller/method dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

To explain the use case in as few words as possible, we have a set of controllers (and associated services) that we want to deprecate. In this same project we have introduced fancy new stuff to take its place. For the simplicity sake, all the same REST endpoints are implemented by both sets of work. The only difference being the first set of controllers are namespaced to /v1/ and the latter /v2/.

To verify that all this new work actually works in production, the goal was to incrementally push traffic in that direction. Whether it is "make 5% of the traffic go to the new stuff" or "for all calls dealing with orders from Factory X go to the new stuff" or some other piece of routing logic.

I'm trying not to touch the old code (that would require retesting all of it), so figured I could just hijack how Spring maps a request to a controller. Initially I thought I could I extend `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and override the `lookupHandlerMethod()` call, but while that method is protected in the Abstract base class the very important map of handlerMethods and urlMap are private: leaving me in the lurch when it comes to providing a differing but existing handlerMethod.

I'd like to leverage as much as I can from the `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` and the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` classes. Currently, without access to the handler maps, I'm debating whether to completely use them, but change the `lookupPath` string and create my own HttpServerRequest class where I've edited the request URI to match my "new" controllers.

Any ideas? I'm hoping there is something I am missing.